# See Fin Ack response to "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" packet

Tags: http, tcp

I am trying to have my program (written using Embarcadero C++ builder and Indy protocol stack) to connect to a proprietary server.  I am supposed to send an HTTP command “GET /hyd/1.s16” at which point the server is supposed to send a bunch of data to me. For some reason my protocol stack send a Fin Ack in response to the "HTTP/1.0 200 OK packet.”

When I run it with a server simulator everything works fine:

1. Client sends Syn
2. Server sends Syn Ack
3. Client sends Ack
4. Client sends Psh, Ack with Get command
5. Server sends Ack
6. Server sends Psh, Ack with "HTTP/1.0 200 OK packet"
7. Server sends data in a reassembled PDU
8. Client sends Ack
9. Server sends data in a reassembled PDU
10. Server sends data in a reassembled PDU
11. Client sends Ack
    ...

[Link to good Wireshark capture](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02170458685899076753)

When the customer runs with the actual server, the protocol stack I am using does not like the “HTTP/1.0 200 OK packet” that the server sends and sends a “Fin Ack” response - Packet 7.

1. Client sends Syn
2. Server sends Syn Ack
3. Client sends Ack
4. Client sends Psh, Ack with Get command
5. Server sends Ack
6. Server sends Psh, Ack with "HTTP/1.0 200 OK packet"
7. Client sends Fin, Ack **** Error ****

[Link to bad Wireshark capture](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=41713430074377684167)

```
TIdTCPClient *TCPClient;

TCPClient->Port = M3R_PORT;
TCPClient->Host =   IntToStr((int) ipAddPt1) + "." +
                                IntToStr((int) ipAddPt2) + "." +
                                IntToStr((int) ipAddPt3) + "." +
                                IntToStr((int) ipAddPt4);
TCPClient->Connect();
TCPClient->IOHandler->Write(m3rData);//"GET /hyd/1.s16 HTTP/1.0\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a");

while (!done) {
    readLine[x] = TCPClient->IOHandler->ReadLn();   // extension-header = ChannelId
    if (readLine[x].Length() <= 0) {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: But where's your code ? Your BadTrace pcap suggests that you're closing the connection before you're supposed to, but as to why, we can not really debug this without seeing what your program does.

Comment: Debug the client code -- find out what it's doing when the error happens.

Comment: I added the code.  It seems to me that the protocol stack is rejecting the Psh Ack not my application code because the Fin Ack is sent 0.18 msec after the server's packet.

Comment: I don't know what we're supposed to make of a Wireshark dump of an encrypted session.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being rejected here. You and the server are speaking HTTP 1.0 without the `keepalive` option. That means a single request/response per connection. Your client is perfectly correct to close the connection after receiving the response.

Comment: This make sense but it does not explain why it works with a simulator and not the real device.  I am not actually establishing an HTTP connection but perhaps I should and then use the keep alive.  If I remember correctly, the person who wrote the device said he used HTTP commands over TCP but did not establish an HTTP connection.  He will be on a ship in the middle of the Pacific for a few weeks so I will have to wait for him to return to do any testing.  Thanks for the idea.